# DNS and IP Configuration for Windows Server 2012 DC

Tags: windows, networking, domain-name-system, ip, domain-controller

I am getting these errors:

```
SERVER  Error   DNS: DNS servers on vEthernet (Intel(R) 82567V-2 Gigabit Network Connection - Virtual Switch) should include the loopback address, but not as the first entry.  Configuration

SERVER  Error   DNS: The list of forwarding servers must not contain the loopback address 127.0.0.0.    Configuration
```

My configuration is as follows:

```
Ethernet adapter vEthernet (Intel(R) 82567V-2 Gigabit Network Connection - Virtual Switch):

   Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . : 
   Description . . . . . . . . . . . : Hyper-V Virtual Ethernet Adapter #2
   DHCP Enabled. . . . . . . . . . . : No
   Autoconfiguration Enabled . . . . : Yes
   Link-local IPv6 Address . . . . . : fe80::3909:6646:5dc7:ed87%18(Preferred) 
   IPv4 Address. . . . . . . . . . . : 192.168.2.20(Preferred) 
   Subnet Mask . . . . . . . . . . . : 255.255.255.0
   Default Gateway . . . . . . . . . : 192.168.2.254
   DHCPv6 IAID . . . . . . . . . . . : 326136252
   DHCPv6 Client DUID. . . . . . . . : 00-01-00-01-1A-A5-AA-05-70-71-BC-7E-BD-47
   DNS Servers . . . . . . . . . . . : ::1
                                       192.168.2.20
                                       192.168.2.254
                                       8.8.8.8
   NetBIOS over Tcpip. . . . . . . . : Enabled
```

What do I need to set the DNS servers to?

Comment: If you're specifying `::1` as a v6 DNS server, you'll need to at least specify one other non-localhost v6 DNS server.

Comment: so IPv6 could be what is triggering the errors? I just need to add more IPv6 IPs.

Comment: To recommend the best practice for configuring your server requires a bit more info - does this DC also run DNS (it likely does unless you've consciously decided to separate them out)? Do you have any other DCs/DNS servers in your environment, or is this the only one?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove the ::1 and 8.8.8.8 from your network card config. Instead go into the actual DNS server and setup a forwarding address to 8.8.8.8

I've seen issues with things not resolving properly for local DNS zones.

Also where ever you used 127.0.0.0 change that to 127.0.0.1

Comment: In this case, I think replacing 127.0.0.0 with 127.0.0.1 would be wrong. It needs to be removed from the list of forwarders completely

Comment: @Newt Yes I agree, but if he setup his DNS server to listen on 127.0.0.0 then that would need to be changed to 127.0.0.1